# Bash on Ubuntu for Windows hangs until I press 'enter'

Tags: windows-10, bash

When I run processes within Bash on Ubuntu for Windows – for example `mongod` or `node` – they will occasionally hang. Once hanging, I can resume them by pressing the `Enter` key in the terminal they are running in.

Why is this happening? Is it a known issue? Is there any fix?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of a bug/feature with the terminal when it is in "QuickEdit" mode. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418886/how-and-why-does-quickedit-mode-in-command-prompt-freeze-applications